# write a static file from my local machine to server without using ftp

Tags: javascript, java, jsf

How to write a static file from local machine to server using java/JSF? ex. After login into web site, the site will automatically read a file from C drive of my local machine and write the file to server

Comment: Do you mean this to happen for a normal user using a normal web browser? That won't be possible: the browser won't allow your server code to access the C drive of the user's local machine. You could add a form to upload it, but that will require the user's intervention.

Comment: The client does not know anything about java (unless you use an applet which you should not) or jsf. So if you can get this working in plain html/javascript you have your solution. But the previous commenter is right, you won't get this to work